# how to download owned assets from unreal engine marketplace on linux?

Tags: unreal-4, assets, unreal, asset-management

From any browser, after you own an asset, clicking on download does nothing.

To me, as many suggest, installing windows is not ok, but that is just my opinion.

Is there any alternative that could let me download stuff I own from unreal engine marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

I first tried [“ue4-mp-downloader”](https://github.com/Allar/ue4-mp-downloader) (as it was the first result on google) but it did not work. Things may have changed and it stopped working.

Then I found [this unofficial UE4 Launcher](https://github.com/nmrugg/UE4Launcher) on the [Unreal Engine forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unofficial-ue4-launcher-for-linux-download-assets-from-the-marketplace/135617), and downloaded a few things w/o any problems!

I used a Google-linked account as a sign-in method (just in case you try something else, this method is working!).

The real problem is that I have already posted this answer on the Unreal Engine forums, but my posts are awaiting approval and I read that may take more than a month! So, as many Linux users are struggling to download even things they bought, I post here in the hope they reach here somehow when they google again about it!

I also wonder if there are any other alternatives? Also, helping to keep any of these projects updated (working) would help a lot!